# Как перейти от Arduino/Micropython к программированию микроконтроллеров на С++?

Tags: c++, esp32

Всем добрый день.

**UPD: Всё что написано ниже есть пространные размышления на тему "правильно заданный вопрос содержит в себе половину ответа". Дабы не обесценивать комментарии под вопросом, оставлю как есть. Никакой критически важной информации там нет.**

Я начинал мигать светодиодом на связке ESP8266+Micropython.
Четыре кнопки + дисплей + 3 датчика + реле + Googleтаблицы через раз укладывали esp32+micropython на лопатки.А это я ещё mqtt не прикрутил и управление с телефона.

Ну и исходники Micropython это - С
Пока с китая ехали ещё пара ESP32 было время подумать и почитать интырнеты.
Уроки в итернетах выглядят [вот так](https://youtu.be/cqVnTgcZwf0?t=13).
Или так: если бы у рыбы была шерсть, то в ней водились бы блохи, они бы писали на с++, а с++ это ардуино...

Как я делал с esp32+micropython
Берешь в руки микроконтроллер. И (если ты не гуру ассемблера) идешь к [производителю](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/devkits).
Он тебе такой: [вот прошивка](https://micropython.org/download/esp32/): компилятор под микропитон и библиотеки(файлы) с классами и методами.
А вот описание [стандартных библиотек](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/index.html#micropython-specific-libraries). Ну и инструкций [как начать](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/tutorial/intro.html#esp32-intro) - вагон.

А для С++ я толком ничего и не нашел. ["лучшая" инструкция что я нашел](https://habr.com/ru/post/530638/) заканчивается ничем, мягко говоря.

И ты такой: "А как по-взрослому?" - "Учите С".
"А С или С++" "В2021 С++, бро"
"Подождите но Ардуино же это же - С++. И работает и все счастливы. Стаковерфлоу, а есть причины не кодить микроконтроллер на с++?" "Если твой микроконтроллер тянет то что ты пишешь, то кодь и получай удовольствие"
"Окей гугл, arduino+esp vs micripython+esp" "Земля и небо, чувак" Здесь для меня камнем преткновения стали работа с sdкартами и с экранами. Если с картой я грешил на железо, то вот пришли новые TFT SPI дисплеи... а скорость та же. Да ещё и с косяками. А если линия коснулась края, то побежали артефакты...

В общем и целом мне не хватает базы для тоо чтобы понять что делать дальше и я не понимаю где эту базу искать.

Задача такая(абстрактная. из серии что нужно знать где почитать). Клюковина опрашивает датчики, собирает данные по mqtt протоколу (для начала), управляет кнопками, рисует живое меню и смайлики на экране, соединяется с вайфаем, отправляет статистику в гугл-таблицы, общается с сервером в интернетах, каким-то чудом принимает команды с andorid'a (а в перспективе и с Iphone) обратно показывает картинки и всё такое, получает и отправляет данные через gsm модуль.
И важный момент(!) - как защитить код на микроконтроллере от копирования.

Мне очень понравился пайтон с его классами. По-этому я выбрал с++, а не с.
Но как начать?

Чем С++ для микроконтроллеров отличается от С++ для ПК?
Могу ли я, грубо говоря, брать скетчи ардуино, копировать код в файл arduino_copy.cpp и запускать?
Где-нибудь ведь должна быть описана разница. (помимо того что надпись void main() убрали под капот)
Где-то централизовано есть наборы стандартных библиотек с [описанием](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/framebuf.html) или нужно лезть на github и читать каждый файл?

Собссно поделитесь статьёй видосом ну или хотя-бы что гуглить.
Как поженить esp32 и с++ и не получить при этом ардуино. но потом без великих проблем переносить библиотеки для ардуино в свои проекты.

Comment: Скетчи Arduino - это и есть C++ по сути. Почти ничем не отличается, кроме некоторых дополнительных удобств для новичков. Я бы сказал, что практически никакого смысла переходить на "тру" C++. "И важный момент(!) - как защитить код на микроконтроллере от копирования." - никак. Кому надо, тот вскроет и дизассемблирует.

Comment: То что один человек закрыл, другой всегда сможет открыть. Однако это не значит что все резко перестали вешать замки на двери. Вопрос всегда целесообразность трудозатрат вскрытия и конечного результата. Человек, который способен вскрыть, быстрее напишет программу такого уровня с нуля. А от гаражного копирования нужно защищаться.

Comment: Для примера.. ESP-wroom-32-devkit, С++, DS18B20, GoogleSheets.
Нужно в течение часа каждую(!) секунду считывать данные с датчика и ВСЕ их записать в гугл таблицы. На Micropython отправка данных занимает 6-9 секунд. Сколько из них длится общение с сервером, а сколько вычисление ключа я так и не разобрался.

Comment: Хотите по-взрослому -- берите С, хотите проблем -- [C++](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/)

Comment: @avp [CppCon 2016: Dan Saks “extern c: Talking to C Programmers about C++”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7Sd8A6_fYU)

Comment: @Dmitrii_Argon, ну перепишите на С++ в среде Ардуино и проверьте. Вообще, можно добавить логирование, чтобы посмотреть что сколько времени занимает. Плюс незачем каждую секунду отправлять данные, достаточно их получать каждую секунду, а отправлять, допустим, раз в 5 минут. По поводу гаражного копирования - если человек взялся извлекать код из вашего контроллера, то уж скорее всего он в своем гараже не первый раз (год) это делает, и найдет как получить то что ему нужно.

Comment: "Я предполагаю ответ в виде "что ДЕЛАТЬ"." - я вам выше написал конкретно что делать: добавить логирование, чтобы понять где узкое место, попробовать отправлять данные не каждую секунду, попробовать переписать на Arduino. Скорее всего уже после того как сделаете отправку менее частой все сильно ускорится.

Comment: C ++ и микроконтроллеры: использование и тестирование
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1081708/Cplusplus-and-microcontrollers-using-and-testing

Comment: Допустим станок работает с частотой 100 штампов в минуту. На линии 7 станков. Вам нужна суточная телеметрия. Влияет ли пуск термической печи в соседнем цеху на износ режущего инструмента. С флешками будете бегать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, сократите вопрос, чтобы он максимально конкретно описывал вашу проблему, без лишних деталей. Сейчас если у кого-то возникнет похожая проблема, ему нужно будет сначала прочитать много текста, прежде чем он доберется конкретно до проблемы.

Comment: @avp, а чего не фортран?

Comment: @PavelGridin, а сами как думаете?

Answer (score 0):

Всегда верил что в России самое лаконичное и нетоксичное коммюнити.

Kolban's book on ESP32 by Neil Kolban
https://leanpub.com/kolban-ESP32

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGozJXuQ8dY&list=PLB-czhEQLJbWMOl7Ew4QW1LpoUUE7QMOo&index=5&ab_channel=KolbanTechnicalTutorials

Правильный запрос в гугл а лучше в ютуб: start ESP-IDF C++
Чудесная сила перевода автоматических субтитров
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IuZ-E8Tmhg&ab_channel=YuriR